# Error: symeig_cpu: the algorithm failed to converge: 6 off-diagonal elements of an intermediate tridiagonal form did not converge to zero

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, torch

I am trying to use https://github.com/Michaelvll/DeepCCA

After 20-40 iterations, It gives the following error:

```
RuntimeError: symeig_cpu: the algorithm failed to converge; 6 off-diagonal elements of an intermediate tridiagonal form did not converge to zero.

Error is generated from https://github.com/Michaelvll/DeepCCA/blob/master/objectives.py#L46

[D1, V1] = torch.symeig(SigmaHat11, eigenvectors=True)
```

System Configuration:

- Windows 10.
- Python 3.7
- Pytorch 1.2.0

How can I debug this?

Answer (score 2):

I have come across a similar error. Its root cause was a failure in the Cholesky decomposition at some point down the road, because a tensor was singular.